# Generate Auto Invoice No in C# with different customers

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop, c#-2.0

everyone so I am working on a C# Winforms application. Where i used to manually input Invoice no like "Inv-1, Inv-2" etc. I want to autogenerate a Unique Invoice Number for every customer.
Like if I have 3 different customers

*1- local
2- global
3- international*

I want to generate "INV-1" for every each of them and further increment every time I sell something to them. I am attaching this image with an example dataset in it. Please help me.

[table for order's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBo3B.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate better exactly what you want? Provide some code sample? Point in the code the specific problem will help too.

Comment: Sir, I have a table where i used to input Invoice number manually like "Inv-1, Inv-2" etc.
so i wanted to generate Invoice No Automatically for every customer i have in this table.

Comment: Can you please show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more organized by turning the "Invoice" into a class with an `int` `Id` property and an `Update` or `Increment` method and override the `ToString` method to append the "INV" string if you think its necessary for your logic.

it's cleaner this way without using string manipulation and regex for a simple task

Note: this is just a sample, you have to provide us with more info and maybe a code sample from your side.

Sample:

```
public class Invoice {

  private int Id;

  public Invoice(int InvoiceId = 0){

     this.Id = InvoiceId;

  }

  public int Increment(){

    Id += 1;

    return Id;

  }

  public override string ToString(){

   return string.Format("INV-{0}",Id);

  }

}
```